# Error HTTP de JSON al insertar un dato en MYSQL desde Angular usando PHP

Tags: php, mysql, json

Tengo un problema al intentar insertar datos en MYSQL usando formularios de Angular comunicado con PHP, al obtener datos si está bien, no me da problemas, pero al insertar datos en la base de datos es el problema.

El error que me da es:

> ```
> HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 200, statusText: "OK", url: "http://localhost/La-Rana-Glotona/server/api/crearproducto.php", ok: false, …}
> error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>) at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:107605:51) at ZoneDelegat...
> message: "Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0"
> stack: "SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0\n    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)\n    at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:107605:51)\n...
> text: "<br />\n<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught Error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\La-Rana-Glotona\\server\\api\\crearproduct...
> message: "Http failure during parsing for http://localhost/La-Rana-Glotona/server/api/crearproducto.php"
> name: "HttpErrorResponse"
> ok: false
> status: 200
> statusText: "OK"
> url: "http://localhost/La-Rana-Glotona/server/api/crearproducto.php"
> ```

Para debuggear comenté todas las líneas en mi archivo php y fui descomentando 1 por 1 y el error está al hacer la sentencia SQL

---

Este es mi código:

**crear-producto.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { ProductosService } from 'src/app/services/productos.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-crear-producto',
  templateUrl: './crear-producto.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./crear-producto.component.css']
})
export class CrearProductoComponent implements OnInit {

  crearProducto: FormGroup;
  enviado = false;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private productosServicio: ProductosService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.crearProducto = this.fb.group({
    titulo_producto: ['', Validators.required]
  });
  }

  get f() {
    return this.crearProducto.controls;
  }

  agregarProducto() {
    this.productosServicio.crearProducto(this.crearProducto.value).subscribe(
      datos => {
        if (datos['resultado']=='OK'){
          alert (datos['mensaje']);
      }
    });
  }

  enviarDatos(){
    this.enviado = true;
    if (this.crearProducto.invalid){
      return;
    }

    this.agregarProducto();
  }

}
```

---

**productos.service.ts**

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ProductosService {

  API_URI = "http://localhost:80/La-Rana-Glotona/server/api/";

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  crearProducto(producto){
    return this.http.post(`${this.API_URI}crearproducto.php`, JSON.stringify(producto));
  }
}
```

---

**crearproducto.php**

```
<?php
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:4200');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');

    $json = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $params = json_decode($json);

    require("conexion.php");

    $con = retornarConexion();

    $query = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO productos(titulo_producto) VALUES ('$params -> titulo_producto')");
    
    class Resultado{};

    $respuesta = new Resultado();
    $respuesta -> resultado = 'OK';
    $respuesta -> mensaje = 'producto creado';

    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($respuesta);
?>
```

---

Esta es la imagen del error que da:

[image: Imagen Error]

---

Esta es la imagen de lo que envía:

[image: Imagen envio]

Muchas gracias de antemano por la ayuda

Comment: El texto devuelto por el servidor es muy claro `text: "<br />\n<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught Error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\La-Rana-Glotona\\server\\api\\crearproduct...`, revisa el mensaje de error completo para saber en qué línea se produce el error, probablemente al insertar. Antes de esa línea agrega `var_dump($params);` ejecuta nuevamente, copia y pega el texto del error en la pregunta. Así podemos saber qué estás recibiendo (tipo de dato y contenido) para tratar de ayudar a resolver el problema.

Comment: En el `DevTools` de Chrome, mira la solapa `Response`, ahí vas a poder ver todos los "errores" que `PHP` esta lanzando. En la captura se ve que tenes un `warning` por la variable `$query` y un `fatal` al intentar convertir a JSON la variable `$respuesta`

Comment: Muchas gracias por sus respuestas amigos, @Triby intente con "var_dump($params);"  agregandolo antes de la sentencia SQL (que es ahí donde me da esta el error) y me arroja este error (y la respuesta que da php @Marcos) ```object(stdClass)#1 (1) {
  ["titulo_producto"]=>
  string(6) "Manuel"
}
<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught Error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in C:\xampp\htdocs\La-Rana-Glotona\server\api\crearproducto.php:14
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\La-Rana-Glotona\server\api\crearproducto.php</b> on line <b>14</b><br />```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

estaba leyendo la documentación de PHP especialmente el "json_encode" y conseguí una solución.

Poner el json_decode en "true" para que lo volviera un array asociativo y funcionó, así quedo el código:

```
<?php
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:4200');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');

    $json = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $params = json_decode($json, true);

    require("conexion.php");

    $con = retornarConexion();

    $query = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO productos(titulo_producto) VALUES ('$params[titulo_producto]')");
    
    class Resultado{};

    $respuesta = new Resultado();
    $respuesta -> resultado = "OK";
    $respuesta -> mensaje = "producto creado";

    echo json_encode($respuesta);
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
?>
```

Muchas gracias a todos por su ayuda.